# Filling a Two-Dimensional Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've declared an array "a[3][3]" (3 x 3) and the user must fill it with 9 integers.

I'm using this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}
```

After I insert numbers `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` and try to print it it outputs: `0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0`

What is the problem?

Comment: The increment step in he second `for` refers to `i`, when it must be `j` so the code has an infinite loop. Is this the actual code (i.e. where is the `print` attempt)?

Comment: I'm looking at this for 2 minutes and didn't notice it :D

Comment: @Arlind Do you know how to use a debugger? If not, see this tutorial - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPnTiFxkn9Y

Comment: I'll vote to close this as "too localized."  It's well asked, but since the problem was a typo in the code, it's unlikely to be useful to others.  Please feel free to ask more questions in the future.

Comment: I'm using Codeblocks and I don't know how to debug.

Answer (score 6):

In your inner for

```
for (j = 0; j < 3; i++)
```

the increment should be j++;

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; /*HERE */j++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}
```

Use the debugger to go step by step and see variable values to investigate such cases on your own in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hate it when this kind of error happens to me. Wasted 40 mins on this :)

Comment: @Arlind You'll not waste 40 mins when you use debugger.

Answer (score 2):

`for (j = 0; j < 3; i++)` should be `for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)`

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing the wrong variable in the inner loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)      // < should be j++, not i++
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}
```

The second `i++` should be `j++`, otherwise the program will never stop asking for number.

This question is quite simple, why not share all you code. I am pretty sure there are only sytax errors.